# How to continue outer loop index from the inner loop index iterrows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing a issue, maybe is not so complicated. I would to like to back to outer loop and continue the code from the index that my inner loop stopped, I am using the same dataframe. Is there another way to achieve that ?

```
def create_freights(self):


    self.connect_sap()
    self.file = self.txt_file.text()

    data = pd.read_excel(self.file)
    data.columns = data.columns.str.replace(" ",'_')
    
    index_2 = 0
    
    for index, row in data[index_2:].iterrows():


        if row.FreightType =="y601" or row.FreightType =="Y601" :
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "tk11"
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRV13A-KSCHL").text = row.FreightType
        

        elif row.FreightType == "Y154" or row.FreightType == "y154" or row.FreightType == "Y161" or row.FreightType == "y161":
            
            self.session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtKOMG-TDLNR").text = row.Serviceagentf
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtKOMG-LAND1A").text = row.CountryofDeparture
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtKOMG-LZONEA").text = row.DepartureZone
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtKOMG-LAND1Z").text = row.DestinationCountry
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtKOMG-YYRDTFRTP").text = row.Equipment
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtKOMG-YYRDTFRTP").setFocus()
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtKOMG-YYRDTFRTP").caretPosition = 4
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey (0)
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMV13ATCTRL_FAST_ENTRY/ctxtKOMG-

        
            data['Check'] = data['ID'].shift(-1)
                
            for index_2, row_1 in data.iterrows():
                                
                CurrentRow = row_1['ID']
                NextRow = row_1['Check']
            
                if NextRow:
                    if CurrentRow == NextRow:

                        
                        self.session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtX_CHAR_VAL").text = " 0,000  A"
                        self.session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtY_CHAR_VAL").text = row_1.KeyRow
                        self.session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtY_CHAR_VAL").setFocus()

                    
                    else: 
                        self.session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey (0)
                        self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press()
                        self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press()
                        self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press()
```

Comment: Don't use `iterrows`, loop over the index and access the rows with `iloc`. That said, what exactly are you trying to do? Are you sure you need to loop?

Comment: The inner loop will only end if all rows are processed (or an exception occurs), so you can't continue outer loop where inner loop stopped.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment by 'mozway', you can use `iloc` instead of `iterrows`, you would iterate over the index of the dataframe and access rows using iloc.

like this:

```
def create_freights(self):
    self.connect_sap()
    self.file = self.txt_file.text()
    data = pd.read_excel(self.file)
    data.columns = data.columns.str.replace(" ", '_')
    index_2 = 0
    
    # Prepare data for the inner loop
    data['Check'] = data['ID'].shift(-1)
    
    for index_1 in range(len(data)):
        row = data.iloc[index_1]
        if row.FreightType in {"y601", "Y601"}:
            # Your code for freight type y601
        elif row.FreightType in {"Y154", "y154", "Y161", "y161"}:
            # Your code for freight type Y154 or Y161
            while index_2 < len(data):
                row_1 = data.iloc[index_2]
                CurrentRow = row_1['ID']
                NextRow = row_1['Check']
                if NextRow:
                    if CurrentRow == NextRow:
                        # Your code for inner loop when NextRow is equal to CurrentRow
                    else:
                        # Your code for inner loop when NextRow is not equal to CurrentRow
                        break  # Exit the inner loop and continue from the outer loop
                index_2 += 1
```

Comment: The line code - data['Check'] = data['ID'].shift(-1) , need to be provide before While loop, right?

Comment: ThehungryCub, I was trying to increase the index_1, when the while stops after first run, the index_2 = 5 , so I would like to back to outer loop and restar index_1 = 6. Do you how I can do that? Thanks in advance.